# Access annotated fields

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I made a custom Annotation for my project which will be used only with fields, that is

`@MyAnnotation int myVariable`

I have another class which will be in charge of performing some actions according to the variables values.The project has an undetermined number of classes with annotations included. How can I access them using my annotations processor in order to access the values?

I can check the annotated variables going though each class, but not modifying the value since is not an object.

any suggestion on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: I also found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875029/how-do-i-get-all-fields-and-properties-of-an-object-that-are-annotated-with-spec) similar to your question

Comment: My previously accepted answer listed still available (at the time of writing this comment) article titled "[How do annotations work](http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/08/06/how-do-annotations-work/)".

Answer (score 20):

```
int getMyVariable(Foo foo) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
 for(Field f:foo.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
  /**
   * Ensure the RetentionPolicy of 'MyAnnotation' is RUNTIME.
   */
   if(f.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)){
   return f.getInt(foo);
  } 
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Comment: Good for finding fields, but sometimes the annotation is on the accessor method.

Comment: Remi D:  Private fields are not a problem, you just need to call field.setAccessible(true);